# How can I make the active blue tab fill the entire height of the background nav bar

Tags: html, css, layout

I have designed a nav bar which is black background and white text.  The active tab should have a blue background.  My css displays the active tab slightly less height than the background nav bar for some reason.  Why?  How can I get the height of the active blue tab match the height of the nav bar?

For my nav bar styles seek to the end of the meyerweb css reset where you see:

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* end of css reset */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

nav a.active {
  background-color: #01adef;
  color: white;
}

a.links:link {
  color: #01ADEF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:visited {
  color: #01adef;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:active {
  color: #01adef;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="support.html">Support</a>
  <a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try `height: 45px` instead of 50px?

Comment: @m4n0 why does that work, or seem to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add  `display:flex;` in `.nav` class & change nav height 50px to min-height: 50px

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* end of css reset */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

nav a.active {
  background-color: #01adef;
  color: white;
}

a.links:link {
  color: #01ADEF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:visited {
  color: #01adef;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:active {
  color: #01adef;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="support.html">Support</a>
  <a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation